# finding derivative at intermediate point of known data set

Tags: numerical-methods, derivatives, interpolation

I have a function $y = f(x)$, $ x \in [0,1]  $ and $ y \in [0,1]$

Set of values $(x_i,y_i)$ are known for n points. I need to find derivative at point $x_{\zeta}$ such that $y(x_{\zeta}) = 0.5$

Now $x_{\zeta}$  generally falls between two data points $x_i \le x_{\zeta} \le x_{i+1}$. How can $\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x_{\zeta}}$ can be best expressed in terms of 
$x_i , x_{i+1}$ ? One option is to take weighted average of derivatives at points $x_{i}$ and $x_{i+1}$

$({x_{i+1}-x_{i}})\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x_{\zeta}} = (x_{i+1}-x_{\zeta})\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x_{i}} +(x_{\zeta}-x_{i}) \frac{dy}{dx}|_{x_{i+1}}$

I want to know if there is better option for calculation taking two points only and as a another question how can I take values of all known points take into account for calculation of derivative?

The function $y$ is non-periodic. If it was periodic Fast Fourier Transform might have been useful.

Comment: So besides the location of the points you also know the derivates at the points and you know that there is a unique $x_\zeta$ such that $f(x_\zeta) = 0.5$, right? Is there more you know, for example, is the function increasing? Also, what does the function represent, that can be important in determining the best option.

Comment: @Paul, there is unique $\zeta$ such $f(x_{\zeta}) = 0.5$, and function is monotonic. function represents interface between to phases and with 0 representing one phase and 1 representing other phase. values of f(x) between 0 to 1 depict linear combination of phases.

Answer (score 2):

1. Choose an interpolation method and use it to reconstruct the function $f$
   based on the known data points.
   Use Google to see commonly used interpolation methods and how
   to use them. You can also make up your own method.
   Choose the interpolation method that you think constructs an $f$ that
   approximates the real $f$ the best.
2. Solve $f(x_\zeta) = 0.5$. ($x_\zeta$ was not given, right?)
3. Calculate $f'(x_\zeta)$.

> I want to know if there is better option for calculation taking two points only and as a another question how can I take values of all known points take into account for calculation of derivative?

Some interpolation methods take all the points into account.
Note that without defining the word "better", no one here can tell you what the best
solution to your problem is. Maybe your current method is already the best.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Paul.  Number of points for which function is defined is very large (n~3000). So I was wondering if instead of using polynomial function as approximation can I use something like Cosine transform to find derivatives.